# Align logo right in Beamer

Tags: beamer, align, margins, backgrounds

I want to *right align* my background image (logo) in Beamer presentation.

What's more I want to set logo to be partially visible - left half of the image should be visible on the right side of the slide and right half of the logo should be outside of the slide.

So far I have following logo definition:

```
\pgfdeclareimage[width=0.3\paperwidth,height=0.3 \paperwidth]{bg}{my-logo}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\pgfuseimage{bg}}
```

The above code positions my logo on the *left* side of the slide such that whole logo is visible.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Have you tried something like this \logo{\includegraphics[height=7mm]{images/logo} \hspace*{2mm}} ?

Comment: This is possible using TikZ and absolute positioning. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but I would just edit the image to look how you want the *entire* background to look. You can then include the entire image with

```
\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{bg}{my-logo-rightside}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\pgfuseimage{bg}}
```

where `my-logo-rightside` is something like this
[image]

Alternatively, you can position the background absolutely using TikZ. Note this will take two runs to get the desired output.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document} 
\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{bg}{example-image}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%\pgfuseimage{bg}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[anchor=west] at (current page.center){\pgfuseimage{bg}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
Foo
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]